# Declaring private variables in a class Google Apps Script V8

Tags: class, google-apps-script

I am trying to declare a class with a private variable in Google Apps Script V8 runtime.
Here is the code:

```
class Exam{
  var examName = "";

  getExamName(){
    return this.examName;
  }
}
```

When I go to save this, I get the following syntax error:

```
Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier line: 2 file: Code.gs
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax isn't really valid: https://v8.dev/features/class-fields#es2015-class-syntax

So using the correct syntax, your snippet could become:

```
class Exam {
  constructor() {
    this._examName = "";
  }
  get examName() {
    return this._examName;
  }
  set examName(value) {
    this._examName = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it. Here is what I am trying to do:

class Exam{
  constructor(){
    this._examName = "";
  }

  getExamName(){
    return this.examName;
  }

  loadQuestions(examName, sheetDetails){
    sheetDetails.values.forEach(function(row, rowId){
        this._examName = sheetDetails.values[rowId][3];
      }
    });    
  }
}

I now get this error:
TypeError: Cannot set property '_examName' of undefined

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That is still not following the syntax I posted on my answer. For example, you define a function called "getExamName", but, in the answer, there is a getter whose name is examName().

Comment: Made the change. Thanks. 
I am getting an error when setting the internal variable to a value in

this._examName = sheetDetails.values[rowId][QBANK_ROUND];
Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: You might want to use a setter for that. I updated the answer to include a setter, but I recommend this guide to understand a bit more about classes in JS: https://javascript.info/class#getters-setters