# How to declare Class fields

Tags: javascript, class, google-apps-script, syntax-error, v8

I'm trying to create a `class` with some fields on Google Apps Scripts.  I can't even save the file.  From what I understand of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608525/what-are-class-fields-in-javascript), I'm using the correct syntax for class fields.

[V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#classes) is enabled.

The error:

```
Syntax error: ParseError: Unexpected token = line: 5 file: Airtable_Class.gs
```

Line 5 is:  `foo = "bar";`

Here's the whole code:

```
class FieldsTest{
  foo = "bar";
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68044338/declaring-private-variables-in-a-class-google-apps-script-v8

Comment: The article that answer references includes, I think, the syntax I'm using: https://v8.dev/features/class-fields#public-class-fields

Comment: Well. Many of examples from the article don't work. I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue. Add a star (★ on top left) to the issue, if you want this to be implemented.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195752915

According to the tracker, it is supported, but it is blocked by the parser.

Comment: I'm confused, that issuetracker item is about static fields, but the OP wasn't trying to  use static fields.

Is it your understanding that GAS doesn't allow using declared fields at all?

Comment: @RobertM. I probably tested it and believe that to be the case then. Apps script, after being based on V8, the underlying V8 engine is regularly updated. So there maybe some updates. Nevertheless, as written in my answer, GAS(V8) supports it, but the parser(which prevents saving the code) is the problem. Unless the parser was updated, the issue would still persist.

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems that Google Apps Script **doesn't** support **static class fields**, it **does** support **static methods/getters/setters**, so you can do this:

```js
class X {
   // ⭐️ static getters & setters
   static get a(){ return this._a || 0 }     // this === X
   static set a(value){ this._a = value }    // this === X
}
```

then you can get/set `X.a` as usual:

```js
X.a      // get: 0.0
X.a = 3  // set: 3.0
X.a      // get: 3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to simulate static fields in Apps Script. It involves using properties instead of a field. We can create a lazily initiated property that replaces itself with a field, using the following code:

```
class MyClass {

  static get c() {
    // Delete this property. We have to delete it first otherwise we cannot set it (due to it being a get-only property)
    delete MyClass.c;
    // Replace it with a static value.
    return MyClass.c = {};
  }

}
```

This approach is better than using a static property, because it also works when instantiating static objects or arrays. To confirm this works, we can use the following:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(MyClass.c === MyClass.c)
```

This will only evaluate to true if the object was generated once and stored. If the field remains a property, it will return false, because the object is generated twice.