# Are private class properties supported in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, class, google-apps-script, private

I attempted to use [Private class features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) in Google Apps Script, using the following snippet:

```
class Feed
{
  #user;
  #password;
  url;
  
  constructor(url, credentials)
  {
    // class constructor
    this.url = url;
    this.#user = credentials.user;
    this.#password = credentials.password;
  }
}
```

with the intention of calling it in the following manner:

```
const url = "https://URL"
const credentials = {user: 'user', password: 'password'};

let feed = new Feed(url, credentials);
```

On saving the file, the following error was displayed, appearing to indicate that private class features aren't supported in Google Apps Script:

```
Syntax error: ParseError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL line: 3 file: Testing.gs
```

I removed the '#' on line three, as shown below:

```
class Feed
{
  user;
  #password;
  url;
  
  constructor(url, credentials)
  {
    // class constructor
    this.url = url;
    this.#user = credentials.user;
    this.#password = credentials.password;
  }
}
```

and received the following error on saving:

```
Syntax error: SyntaxError: Private field '#user' must be declared in an enclosing class line: 11 file: Testing.gs
```

I searched, and found [Define private class fields with Google Apps Scripts (GAS) V8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132189/define-private-class-fields-with-google-apps-scripts-gas-v8) which indicated that (at the time) private class features weren't supported in Google Apps Script. While the first error message seems to confirm that this is the case, the second implies that Apps Script understands private class fields.

Questions:

- Are private class fields supported by Google Apps Script (v8)?
- If so, how are they supposed to be implemented?

Thanks,

Fergal

Comment: Private class fields are probably not supported yet (even though the error suggests otherwise). You can fallback on using closures and `WeakMap`s for the time being.

Comment: I reported the inconsistent error messaging via https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239767510. We'll see what they come back with.

Comment: Confirmed as a known issue, and something that they are working on, but not available yet.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot Can those same workarounds be used for methods as well?

Comment: @RobertM. Yup. You can define the equivalent of a private method using closures. That's pretty much how its always been done. It's only within the last few years that Javascript gained native support for features such as Classes; and even then its just syntactic sugar, the language still uses Prototypal Inheritance under the hood.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot Thank you sir. in a sense all high level languages are syntactic sugar, it's all machine code under the hood.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot Would you be willing to give me a clue about how to do this? I can't figure it out. I need to create private variables and functions.

Comment: @RobertM. Just google the relevant keywords. There are numerous articles online that go into depth on the topic.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot I did. I have been for days. I couldn't find one that explained it in the context of classes. There were some good ones showing how to create functions with private variables, but not classes. Please, could you suggest a article if you're aware of one? I'm banging my head against this.

Comment: @RobertM. Do a Google search with the following string of keywords `javascript private members closures weakmap`. You should see a number of articles referencing the technique with many of them involving classes.